# Can't pass method as delegate

Tags: c#, delegates

I would like to pass this method

```
private void activityStreamDownloaded(TaskNotification tn)
{
    //Logic
}
```

with `Delegate ad = activityStreamDownloaded;` to the method

```
public void AddNextTask(WebAPITask task, Delegate callback)
{
    //Error: Callback is variable but is used like a method
    task.OnExecuted += () => callback(task.TaskNotification);
}
```

like this `_taskList.AddNextTask (new TaskObj(), ad);`

Why is this happening and how can I solve this?

Comment: Delegate has a method named Invoke I believe. You can't just invoke them like they are actual functions. They are objects.

Comment: You need to be more specific about what is the delegate type. `Delegate` has no signature and thus you can't invoke it just like that. It is just a abstract base class. Looks like you need `Action<TaskNotification>`

Comment: @SriramSakthivel where do I need that?

Comment: Change  `AddNextTask` method signature to `public void AddNextTask(WebAPITask task, Action<TaskNotification> callback)`. I'm guessing, without knowing what is `task.TaskNotification` property, only this much I can guess :)

Answer (score 0):

As pointed out in the comments `Delegate` is an abstract class. Instead try something like this;

```
// declare an action type (basically a delegate with void return type)
Action<TaskNotification> callback = activityStreamDownloaded;


// update method signature to take an Action<TaskNotification>
public void AddNextTask(WebAPITask task, Action<TaskNotification> callback)

// this code should work now
_taskList.AddNextTask (new TaskObj(), callback);
```